# MAAS open ports between region and rack controller

Tags: maas

Which ports are used for region to rack controller and vv communication?

Answer (score 2):

found the answer in the documentation: https://docs.ubuntu.com/maas/2.2/en/installconfig-rack

"In regards to region controller and rack controller communication, each rack controller must be able to initiate TCP connections:

for HTTP, to each region controller on port 5240. If high availability is implemented then this will typically become port 80. See MAAS HA.
for RPC, to each region controller between port 5250 and 5259 inclusive. This permits up to 10 maas-regiond processes on each region controller host. At present this is not configurable."